# ActiveReport3 subReport iteration

Tags: activereports

how can I 
    walk cycle for details subreport(2 textboxes) for make a second textbox strictly under the first but right allign.
    Or how else would be a way to indicate that the second textbox has been located under the first but right(allign right)

```
example 

good name

               price 
another good

name

               price



    `public void Goods_BeforePrint()
{
     Section sec;
     sec = rpt.Sections["Goods"];
    for(int y= 0; y <= sec.Controls.Count - 1;y++)
    {
    if( y%2> 0)
    {
        sec.Controls[y].Height +=   sec.Controls[y-1].Height;
        ((TextBox)sec.Controls[y]).Text   = System.Convert.ToString(sec.Controls.Count);

    }
}`
```

For now I have 0.25 value of Height in every row.
Problem not in allign but in size of rows, because here not have iteration what I expect  and each rows is same size = size of first row.

Comment: it does not actual. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear; however on the basis of the expected output, I would suggest you to handle the Format event of the SubReport's detail section and access the control which you want to change the alignment for. So if you want it to appear left aligned twice and right aligned for every third row, the following code should work:

```
int counter = 0;
private void detail_Format(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    if (counter % 3 == 0)
    {
        this.txtCountry1.Alignment = GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.Section.TextAlignment.Right;
    }
    else
    {
        this.txtCountry1.Alignment = GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.Section.TextAlignment.Left;
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot from my machine showing a basic example with similar implementation.
[image]

Comment: Thanks , I had needed that and in future I will.

Comment: You may want to upgrade to ActiveReports 9 since ActiveReports for .NET 3.0 has been discontinued long time back.